# Transitioning to ACM Certificates for SSL Connections - Redshift

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

Not sure if this is off topic or too specific.

I currently connect with python to my redshift cluster using something like this:

```
conn_string = "postgresql+psycopg2://%s:%s@%s:%d/%s" % (db_user, db_pass, host, port, schema)
conn = sqlalchemy.engine.create_engine(conn_string,
                                       execution_options={'autocommit':True},
                                       encoding='utf-8',
                                       connect_args={"keepalives": 1, "keepalives_idle": 60, "keepalives_interval": 60},
                                       isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT")
```

I understand that if I have SQL client such as SQLWorkbenchJ, I have to update the drivers and such. However I have not been able to find much about what to do if you connect using something like the code I just put above.

Will it continue to work fine? or the libraries (in this case, psycopg2) should update how they connect and I need to upgrade it? Not 100% of what to do here.

Ideas?

**EDIT** I'm actually not experiencing any issues, just trying to prevent one though, I forgot to add the link to the notification I received from AWS:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-transitioning-to-acm-certs.html

Comment: AWS ACM certificates are for load balancers, CloudFront distributions, and API Gateway. They aren't used with Redshift. I also don't see anything in your code example that is doing anything special with SSL certificates. Perhaps you need to clarify your question with details about the exact issue you are experiencing.

Comment: @MarkB Please see my edit, you're right, I needed to clarify a little.

Comment: OK, so if you read that notice, the first thing it says is it won't affect you if you aren't setting `sslMode` to `require`, `verify-ca` or `verify-full`. I don't see you doing that in your connection code.